# Can't store bytes in rethinkDB

Tags: python, rethinkdb

So my issue is, that I encrypted some passwords, stored it on my rethinkDB like this:

```
"b'bytesandstuff'"
```

But if I retrieve it and try to decode it, it crashes out due to the string not being a byte, what's the easiest way to fix this?

Also, I don't think I need to provide code for this, but I will do anyways

main.py

```
from passgen import encryptPass, decryptPass

global decpass
encpass = loginquery.get("password")
decpass = decryptPass(encpass)
```

passgen.py

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = "mySecretKey"
f = Fernet(key)

def decryptPass(rawstring):
    decrypted = f.decrypt(rawstring)
    converted = decrypted.decode('utf8')

    return converted
```

Edit: I'm using Python 3.6.4

Edit 2: One record looks like this: [RethinkDB Sample Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyO2z.png)

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: @amirouche Edited post, added Python version

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as accepted (and +1...) if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have bytes as input and you want to store it as a string you can encode it in base 64 using [base64.b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/base64.html) first and then decode the string in `ascii` before storing in rethinkdb.

```
In [1]: import base64

In [2]: encrypted_message_as_returned_by_fernet = b'c0ffee'

In [3]: still_bytes = base64.b64encode(encrypted_message_as_returned_by_fernet)

In [4]: string = still_bytes.decode('ascii')

In [5]: type(string)
Out[5]: str

In [6]: # do the reverse operation before decyphering the thing

In [7]: base64.b64decode(string.encode('ascii'))
Out[7]: b'c0ffee'
```

The question is why you can't simply do `encrypted_message_as_returned_by_fernet.decode('ascii')`. It's because bytes type can contains null bytes like `b'\0'` which might not play well with some systems if it's found inside a string.

To be safe use base64 anytime you need a string representation of bytes. It's not Python specific. Images for instance, are base 64 to be included directly in html pages. It's called [data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)